# my API dose not work on flutter and return 404

Tags: android, asp.net, flutter, api, asp.net-core

Hi I training to work with API in flutter, my API work correctly on ASP.net mvc .net core and when I want signup user with postman everything work correct. but in flutter i get the 404 error. here this 3 images is my code. 1: api code. 2.flutter code. and the error 3.postman screenshot

how can I fix this?[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The flutter is not at same server with that API application?

Comment: my server for now is local iis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Url, protocol type and port in postman different from in your code.
By the way when using HTTP,doesn't need to add 80 port in url "http://192.168.1.118:80".

2- Please check your parameter that isn't null or undefined.